# Matplotlib and Numpy: Log plot with high order numbers

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot several points using Matplotlib on a plot that has lines following the function defined in energy(). The points are plasma parameters and the lines follow the function that connects them using multiple values of the Debye length.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n_pts = [10**21,10**19,10**23,10**11,10**15,10**14,10**17,10**6]
KT_pts = [10000,100,1000,0.05,2,0.1,0.2,0.01]  

n_set = np.logspace(6,25)
debye_set = 7.43*np.logspace(-1,-7,10)

def energy(n,debye):
    return n*(debye/7430)**2

fig,ax=plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(n_pts,KT_pts)

for debye in debye_set:
    ax.loglog(n_set,energy(n_set,debye))

plt.show()
```

This gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'log'
```

Comment: Whenever you report a Python error, always include the *complete* error message (i.e. the complete traceback).  It includes useful information, such as the line that triggered the error.

Comment: Your code runs fine for me; no errors.

Comment: Also runs fine for me with Python 3.6 on Mac

Answer (score 1):

Python does automatic, weird things for integers larger than can be held as a 64-bit integer (on 64 bit systems), like 10**21.  In doing so, numpy will then not automatically use a numpy dtype for such objects, instead using the object dtype.  This, in turn, does not support ufuncs like np.log:

```
> np.log([10**3])
array([ 6.90775528])
> np.log([10**30])
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'log'
```

One easy solution here is to make sure that numpy converts n_pts, the array with the large numbers, into a dtype it can actually use, like float:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n_pts = np.array([10**21,10**19,10**23,10**11,10**15,10**14,10**17,10**6], dtype='float')
KT_pts = [10000,100,1000,0.05,2,0.1,0.2,0.01]

n_set = np.logspace(6,25)
debye_set = 7.43*np.logspace(-1,-7,10)

def energy(n,debye):
    return n*(debye/7430)**2

fig,ax=plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(n_pts,KT_pts)

for debye in debye_set:
    ax.loglog(n_set,energy(n_set,debye))

plt.show()
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I was thinking it had something to do with the numbers being too big.